# Is the water potable in Swiss mountain huts?

Tags: health, switzerland, mountains, tap-water

Swiss mountain huts often have running water (for toilets and handwashing), but usually signage that state the water is not potable for drinking.

Is this sign for one's own benefit (and health), just a CYA (cover-your-ass) strategy for the hut, or a tactic intended to sell more bottled water (usually at *ridiculous* prices)?

In addition to avoiding the cost of the water sold in the hut, I feel it's not really eco-friendly to helicopter in a ton of water bottles and then have to dispose of the waste. Nobody needs an excuse to hydrate less (especially in the mountains), but obviously not catching any weird bugs is important too.

Comment: Have you considered using a LifeStraw? (http://www.buylifestraw.com/en/)

Comment: Better to not risk...I am at the Hospital, due to a reaktive atrosys caused by bacteria Infektion... Bacteria that i got drinking water two weeks ago in a Switzerland.Hut.

Comment: Mountain water is mostly clean unless it gets contaminated by dead animals or other shit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Water regulations in Switzerland are very strict and most tap water is of impeccable quality. There is also a law which states that any fountain, which doesn't have regulated drinking water, has to be declared as such, so if you see a fountain with no sign on a village square, it's very likely safe to be drunk. This is most likely the reason why there is a sign at those huts.

The situation in mountain huts is a bit different. They are very rarely connected to any piping and the water most often comes from a local spring. In some cases, especially in very high altitude locations and in winter, there might not be any source available, and there is places where drinking water has to be brought up (mostly where cable cars are available).

So most probably the water comes directly from a fresh water spring (a big percentage of Swiss water reaches the taps unfiltered from some spring). Probably the quality is not monitored however as it would be with public tap water, so it can get tainted (after a lot of rain), or be from a non clean spring. Note that if it's melting water (from glaciers or snow), then it will generally also be unsafe.

Providing clean water at such remote places often comes with a lot of expenses for the owner. There are certain places where restaurant owners will charge you very high prices if you order tap water at the restaurant.

So, you will probably be safe drinking the water. However, there is a small chance that the water might be tainted and unsafe. The only one who will be able to tell you is probably the owner.

Note, if there are locals around, you can ask them and they might know of alternative source to fill up your water bottles. As a kid, (I grew up in the Swiss Alps), we always knew of a couple of springs near my grandparents chalet where it would be safe to drink from.

Comment: Why would snowmelt or unfiltered mountain running freshwater be considered unsafe? I mean, they're not regulated or tested, but in practice these would be the cleanest natural water sources assuming that there are no industrial plants or farms above you in that mountain. Is this a distinction between "not safe" and "not *certified* as safe" or a practical concern?

Comment: I have the same question as @Peteris: why would melted glacial water be "generally unsafe"?

Comment: @Peteris The original water source may be perfectly fine - but if there is any kinid of water conduit, it's really hard to keep microorganisms, mostly bacteria, from enjoying the water too! I would not see that as a real problem personally, because almost all of these bacteria enyoy life at homi in their biofilm, and would be dead from saliva before our imune system even notices. But technically, it's not clean.

Comment: @Peteris snow and ice is quite dirty (microbes, dead animals, dust, deer pee). At a normal, safe source the water has passed through soil and rocks for a very long time (days up to years) and has been cleaned that way. That's why a ground water pumping station cannot be too close to a river. So when you have a mountain source, without having more information, you have no way of knowing whether it's clean water that has passed through a lot of ground layers or whether it's dirty melt water which has just passed through a couple meters.

Comment: Just to add - the water may be kept in tanks/piping that are not clean/rusty whatever, and present a hazard, even if the water as it goes in is clean.

Comment: For those who are not aware, "source" can mean "spring", where water naturally flows from. In English otherwise, "source" just means "where you get something" or "origin".

Comment: @hippietrail thanks, that also explains some of the confusion. This is a translation error from my native language (German), which I keep on making. I changed it to make it clearer

Comment: @drat: No worries. I knew source meant spring in French so I figured it out (-:

Comment: On a very hot bike ride on a Swiss Sunday we found all the small village markets closed and our two liter water bottles very empty. I can assure you that the public fountain water is potable because if not we would have all been very sick. Several different villages' fountains, in fact. We were told later that some of the fountains dated to the time before running water in homes.

Comment: A spring is a source of water anyway.

Comment: certain fountains in mountain areas are declared not safe either because they don't respect regulations so they're not sure, or because they really at risk because the water travels under a cow pasture. 

So, if there's nothing written, you can drink it, if there's a notice, you're taking a risk, I don't know how big.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes.**

It is safe to drink water in Swiss mountain huts.  Huts are generally high in the mountains and the water comes straight from melting snow and ice or from springs.  It may not bear the certificate of the Swiss authorities, but pretty much everybody who visits mountain huts drinks this water.  Some do sell bottled water but you absolutely don't need to purchase that.

I've personally done hundreds of hikes in the Swiss alps, and many of my family and friends have been hiking there all their lives.  Most drink from streams or public taps low or high in the mountains and I've never heard of any problems.  I've never seen people carrying filters either.

Comment: There are many huts between 1500-2000 m, an altitude where livestock grazes in the summer. Some are higher and perhaps safer but it's not “generally” the case.

Comment: Note that water from melting snow or ice is not generally safe to drink.

Comment: [This question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48186/how-correct-is-my-intuition-that-tap-water-is-safer-in-the-mountains-than-in-cit/48220#48220) has some related answers that may be relevant ... I'm dubious that you can guarantee the safety of all hut water.

Comment: I don't know about Colorado, I'm talking about Switzerland (I've only ever hiked ½ day in Colorado, but I've done hundreds of hikes in Switzerland).  In Switzerland there are many public water sources either in the [valley](http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/58598370.jpg) or high in the mountains.  Many hikers drink from those, including all I know.  I have never heard of anybody having any problems.  The stomach doesn't need ultra-filtered water.

Comment: @drat Citation needed.  I've been drinking water from melting snow and ice all my life, as have my family and friends.  The only problem is that water from glaciers often is full of sand and stones so it may not feel very pleasant, but it doesn't make ill either.  Bacteria that live by making mammals sick aren't going to thrive in glacier ice that froze 1000 years ago.

Comment: OP is talking about a water source where it's specifically written that it's non-potable. If there's nothing written, of course it's safe!

Comment: At mountain huts they write *non-potable* to boost sales of drinks.

Comment: @gerrit I was looking for some sources, but you are right, there doesn't seem to be much about it. It seems that you are fine as long as you see where the melting water is coming from (clean snow, clean ice), but should watch out when you don't know where the water is coming from. However, note that the signs non-potable, while certainly also a way of making more sales, they are also a legal requirement for non-certified water. Of course they don't always (or even most of the time) mean that you can't drink the water.